# Multiple execution of a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, next.js

```
export default function MyQuestions() {
  const router = useRouter();

  const [auth, setAuth] = useState(false);

  const checkAuth = async () => {
    const loggedInUsername = await getUsername();
    if (router.query.username === loggedInUsername) return setAuth(true);
    return;
  };
  checkAuth();
```

This is a part of a React component where I execute the checkAuth function. I thought it should execute only once but that is not the case. It is executed 4 times and if I remove the returns it is executed even more than 10 times and I don't understand why. In js a function that reaches the end should stop automatically.
Why does this happen?

In this code router is of Next.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are the conditions under which the check should be re-run? This is what [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) is intended for. `useEffect` accepts a function to run the desired effect, and a list of dependencies to specify when an effect should be run -

```js
import { useRouter } from ...
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"

function MyQuestions() {
  const router = useRouter()
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState(false)
  
  useEffect(async () => {
    const loggedInUsername = await getUsername()
    if (router.query.username === loggedInUsername)
       setAuth(true)
  }, [getUsername, router.query.username, setAuth])
  
  return <>...</>
}
```

**Any** free variable inside the effect **must** be listed as a dependency of the effect. There's one issue however. `setAuth` will be a new function each time `MyQuestions` is rendered. To ensure `setAuth` will be the same for each render, we can use [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) -

```js
import { useRouter } from ...
import { useEffect, useCallback, useState } from "react"

function MyQuestions() {
  const router = useRouter()
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState(false)

  const authenticate =
    useCallback(_ => setAuth(true), [])
  
  useEffect(async () => {
    const loggedInUsername = await getUsername()
    if (router.query.username === loggedInUsername)
       authenticate()
  }, [getUsername, router.query.username, authenticate])
  
  return <>...</>
}
```

Now the effect will only re-run when `getUsername`, `router.query.username` or `authenticate` changes. Considering `getUsername` and `authenticate` are functions and should not change, we can expect that the effect will only re-run when `router.query.username` changes.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used `nextjs` but i suppose it happens because it is executed on every render of the router component.

If you want to use it once, just call it in a use effect when the component mounts.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    checkAuth();
}, []) // This will run once, when the component mounts
```

Comment: in this setup, `checkAuth` can run a maximum of one time. this is probably not intended as i'm sure the user should be able to login/logout/re-login. also any free variables need to be declared as a dependency of the effect.

Comment: This piece of code is to check if who is viewing this page is authorized to view specific things. In general anyone can view this page

Comment: A think I noticed is that, as specified by Mamunur, setting state in React causes a re-render. Thus if I do the comparison between router and loggedInUsername and then instead of setting setAuth(true) I execute for exemple a console.log(), the function is performed half the time (of course if I execute it outside the useEffect, as it is in the piece of code I presented)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to return the setState call:

```
    const checkAuth = async () => {
        const loggedInUsername = await getUsername();
        if (router.query.username === loggedInUsername) setAuth(true);
    };
```

Also because you are calling the checkAuth() function right after you call it. Setting state in React causes a re-render. So the reason it is executed 4 to 10 times is because your MyQuestion component re-renders when you setState(), and when it rerenders, is hits the checkAuth() function again and the cycle repeats.

As mentioned put the functionality in a useEffect() with an empty dependency array:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        const loggedInUsername = await getUsername();
        if (router.query.username === loggedInUsername) return setAuth(true);
    }, [])
```

Comment: if you use an empty dependency array, this effect can only be run a maximum of one time. note all free variables in an effect must be listed as a dependency.